# The correct approach to create multi-argument functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I thought about the correct approach to create functions in JavaScript functional programming and Ramda.

We have `deviceTypes`, collection of `devices` and object with `filter`:

```
const deviceTypes = {
    phone: 'phone',
    tv: 'tv',
    watch: 'watch',
}

const devices = [
    {
        title: "My awesome watch",
        type: deviceTypes.watch,
    },
    {
        title: "My awesome phone",
        type: deviceTypes.phone,
    }
]

const filter = {
    deviceType: [deviceTypes.watch]
}
```

Now, I want to show devices filtered by `deviceType` and add to title some text.

I created a functions:

```
const extendTitle = ({item, ...rest}) => ({ title: `${item.title} - Hello world`, ...rest })
const filter = filter(({type}) => filter.deviceType.includes(type))

const filterAndExtendTitle = pipe(
    filter,
    extendTitle
)

filterAndExtendTitle(devices)
```

Now, I have a question. How should I  write function if I want to add second an argument with `deviceTypes` (pure function)?

I was try...

```
const extendTitle = ({item, ...rest}) => ({ title: `${item.title} - Hello world`, ...rest })
const filterItemsByType = (filter) => filter(({type}) => filter.includes(type))

const filterAndExtendTitle = (filter) = pipe(
    filterItemsByType(filter),
    extendTitle
)

filterAndExtendTitle(devices)(filter.deviceType)
```

**... and works fine but I don't know if that practice is good with best practices. I thought about `curry` function and modifications with that to refactor.**

Answer (score 1):

Using Ramda and curried functions you could create a few helper functions that can be reused

(e.g. deviceTypeFilter below)

```js
const { filter, assoc, curry, propSatisfies, map, pipe, contains } = R;

const deviceTypes = {
  phone: 'phone',
  tv: 'tv',
  watch: 'watch'
};

const deviceList = [
  {
    title: "My awesome watch",
    type: deviceTypes.watch,
  },
  {
    title: "My awesome tv",
    type: deviceTypes.tv,
  },
  {
    title: "My awesome phone",
    type: deviceTypes.phone,
  }
];

const itemTitle = (item) => `${item.title} - Hello world`;
const assocTitle = (item) => assoc('title', itemTitle(item), item);

const deviceTypeFilter = curry(
  (filterTypes, items) => filter(
    propSatisfies(contains(R.__, filterTypes), 'type'), 
    items
  )
);

const filterByTypeWithTitle = (filterTypes, devices) => pipe(
  deviceTypeFilter(filterTypes),
  map(assocTitle)
)(devices)


const result = filterByTypeWithTitle([deviceTypes.watch, deviceTypes.phone], deviceList);
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```